# SoapClient stays loading until timeout

Tags: php, web, soap, wsdl

I'm trying to get informations from a Web Service with SoapClient, but for some reason, when I execute the code, it stays loading until timeout, and doesn't show any error. I already tried to set `php.ini` with `extension=php_openssl.dll` and set `extension=php_soap.dll`, tried to execute the code in xampp, in a website hosting and the error persists. In a moment I thought it was a problem in the page, but the link works fine `https://ws.correios.com.br/calculador/CalcPrecoPrazo.asmx?WSDL`.

Here is my function:

```
    $options = [
    'cache_wsdl'     => WSDL_CACHE_NONE,
    'trace'          => 1,
    'stream_context' => stream_context_create(
        [
            'ssl' => [
                'verify_peer'       => false,
                'verify_peer_name'  => false,
                'allow_self_signed' => true
            ]
        ]
    )
];

    $client = new SoapClient('https://ws.correios.com.br/calculador/CalcPrecoPrazo.asmx?WSDL', $options);
    
    $parametros = array('nCdServico' => '04510', 'sCepOrigem' => '82220020', 'sCepDestino' => '08090284');
    
    $response = $client->CalcPrazo($parametros);
    
    var_dump($response);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're not seeing any errors it might be possible, that display_errors is inactive in your environment. What you can do to troubleshoot is to register an error handler as described in the first example
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php#example-468
Then you should see any errors that occur.